# flex android action script native extension

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, air-native-extension

I designed a native extension for android in flex and i have a problem with this extension.
I have packaged the ane file, I have added to the android flex project and it compiles correctly but at runtime I have an error that says that my action script extension class is not found.

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class myClass could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a long painstaking 1 week of try and fail. The problem is that when the action script library project compiles into .swf, packs in this swf an library.swf file. This library.swf needs to be copied into the directory where the actual native android code (.jar) is. Then when you package the .ane file this library.swf is also package.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say on this description. I made some native extentions, if you can - you can provide some code of your jar file and action script intermediate classes.

Did you read this articles and examples, maby they can help you:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt4.html

Comment: I have readed all the documentation regarding building and deploying ane. I have no error at compile time only at runtime is the problem, the class about flex complains is the class from the flex library project not from android native project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the ANE is getting packaged with your application? You need to add it to your project **and** check the package option.

Check [this](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/815) for a quick guide:

Comment: I have verified and my ane is added to the project and is exported correctly.